# Is there a function $f$ with $f'(x) = e^x * f(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, exponential-function

***Edit*** : I'm ''derivation'' and ''integration'' beginner. So I don't have any techniques to solve equations like that.This why I think there have to be a clever trick to solve this. a), b), c) was okay. You can see my solution below. I want to emphasize that I don't want to see the solution. Maybe someone can show me the techniques for $b)$? I found a $f$ in b), c) only with try and error. If you show me the trick, I would  try again $c)$ and $d)$ by my own.

Are there any functions $f$ with following equations:

$ a) f'(x) =e^x + f(x)   $  a) is clear now. Thank you for all of your help

$ b) f'(x) =e^x \cdot f(x) $ solved BUT only with try and error. what is the beginner technique ( like I said: Im a beginner ) to find $f$?

$ c) f'(x) =e^x \cdot f(x)^2 $ solved BUT only with try and error. what is the beginner technique to find $f$?

$ d) f'(x) =e^{f(x)} $

***Remark*** : $f$ is not a constant function.

***Update***: $a ) f:= x \cdot e^x $. Then we use the multiplication rule for derivation. $f'$ = $x \cdot e^x + 1 \cdot e^x = x \cdot e^x + e^x$.

***Update2*** b) $f:= c \cdot e^{e^x}.$ Then we can use the chain rule: $f' = c \cdot e^{e^x} \cdot e^x$.

***Update3*** c) $f:= - \frac{1}{e^x +c}$. Then use chain rule and quotient rule: $ f' = e^x \cdot  \frac{1}{(e^x +c)^2}$

Comment: Well, what do you think about the problem, and what exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: With the level of detail you've put into this question, why not just [go ask Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27+%3D+e%5Ex+%2B+y)?

Comment: hint: a) is a linear ODE. b), c), and d) are separable.

Comment: Do you know how any techniques to try solving any of these differential equations?  If so, which ones?

Comment: What is $(xe^x)'$?

Comment: Hello Jacob Gross,  Believe me: We don't see any techniques to solve equations like that. Last week we start with derivation and talked about the chain rule and things like that, but not about differential equations. We dont even know what differential equations are. Like I said: I don't  want the answer.  All I want is to see is how I can solve equations like that ( the techniques ).

Comment: The general result is that a first-order ODE $y'(x) = f(y(x), x)$ with $f$ continuous on a neighborhood of $p\in \mathbb{R}^2$ has a solution on some (smaller) neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: Comment on your "update 2 edit" - notice that the constant in front doesn't need to be $2$ - it can be any real number you want. See my answer where I used the constant $A$. You can use similar methods (integration) to find the solutions to c) and d), as long as you know how to integrate things like $\frac1{f^2}$ and $e^{-f}$

Comment: @Memories I voted to close this question in part because it lacked context, but also because it was *too broad*.  You are asking four different questions.  It would be better if you asked each one separately, giving good context for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

a) This can be rearranged as $$\frac{df}{dx}-f=e^x$$
You can then use the method of [integrating factors](http://weber.itn.liu.se/~krzma/DS2017/Integrating%20factor%20method.pdf) to solve it.

b) This can be rearranged as $$\frac1f\frac{df}{dx}=e^x$$Then integrate both sides with respect to $x$. Since (c) and (d) use the same method, I'll go a bit further in this example. Integrating with respect to $x$ gives $$\require{cancel}\int\frac1f\frac{df}{\cancel{dx}}\cancel{dx}=\int e^x dx\\\int\frac1fdf=\int e^xdx\\\ln f=e^x +c\\f(x)=e^{e^x+c}=Ae^{e^x}$$ for some arbitrary constant $A$.

c) Similar to (b), rearrange as $$\frac1{f^2}\frac{df}{dx}=e^x$$ and integrate with respect to $x$.

d) Again, rearrange as $$e^{-f}\frac{df}{dx}=1$$and then integrate with respect to $x$.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Hello John Doe. First of all: Thank you for your hints! :) I also don't understand why someone downvotes this answer. So I understand what you have done, but unfortunately we never used the term df/dx. Im pretty sure that it is not allowed to me to reduce dx and consider df, Is there a other,maybe similar beginner trick? By the way: Thanks to you I found c) ! :)

Comment: @Memories The usual method for this is to "multiply" by $dx$ to the other side of the equation. I use quotation marks because of course $\frac{df}{dx}$ isn't actually a fraction. You'll likely learn this method eventually. Another way of viewing this is as [integration by substitution](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/integration-by-substitution.html). Then, when you have$$\int\frac1{f^2}f'(x)dx=\int e^x dx$$you can interpret the LHS as a substitution, you can integrate as if $f$ is the variable and you'll notice that when you differentiate your answer wrt $x$, you get the same result

Answer (score 2):

$$f′(x)=e^x+f(x)\Longleftrightarrow f'-f =e^x\Longleftrightarrow(fe^{-x})'=1\Longleftrightarrow fe^{-x}=x-c\Longleftrightarrow f(x)= e^x(x+c)$$

Answer (score -1):

In order to be sure whether such a function exist you would need to solve the differential equations. b),c) and d) can be solved by separation of variables. a) is on the form $$y^\prime(x) + P(x)y(x) = Q(x), \ \ P(x) = -1,  \ \ Q(x) = e^x$$
and can thus be solved by the method of integrating factor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor.